# How to enforce Protocol class definitions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Python 3.8 recently introduced Protocol classes, super helpful for defining class method signatures. I'm using them as part of a factory method, something like:

```
class Thing(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_thing(self, thing_id: int, action: str, monitor: bool = True) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

and our factory method is defined something like:

```
def provider_factory(some_data: dict) -> Thing:
    if some_data['type'] == Thing.ThingTypes.TypeA:
        return TypeAProcessor(some_data)
    elif some_data['type'] == Thing.ThingTypes.TypeB:
        return TypeBProcessor(some_data)
    ....

my_thing = provider_factory(some_data)
my_thing.do_thing(thing_id=1, action="foo")
...
```

This works great - anyone wanting to implement a new `TypeProcessor` can clearly infer that it will require a `do_thing` method, along with the required signature, etc.

However, this is a legacy app currently being modernized, so enforcing type checking during build / test isn't possible yet - far too many older parts of the code will fail.

Is there some way to selectively enforce, at run-time, that anything returned by the `provider_factory` conforms to the protocol class definitions, and raise a runtime error if not? The `typing` module comes with the decorator `@typing.runtime_checkable`, but it requires writing an explicit `assert isinstance(MyTypeProcessor, Thing)`, which I'd like to avoid (also related to the legacy nature of this app).

tl;dr: Can I enforce Protocol class type checks at runtime other than `assert`ing with `@typing.runtime_checkable`?

Comment: The fact that you are using `typing` suggests you are using a tool like `mypy`. I'm not sure it's worth providing run-time type checks if you don't already have them and are moving towards doing static-type checking as part of the build process.

Comment: @chepner I'd like to get to a point where I can add typing checks like `mypy` but the code base isn't anywhere near ready for it :(

Comment: Adding type hints is far easier than adding run-time checks. The entire type-hinting system is designed around the idea of *gradual typing*, which lets you add hints to part of the code without requiring hints *everywhere* in the code.